# Bad right margins in List of Tables and List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, margins

I have a huge problem with the right margin of my List of Figures and List of Tables. Some words ignore the right margin. Time periods, I've written like this (2071-2100) also don't appear in a acceptable way in the list of figures and list of tables and just ignore the margin. Abbildung means figure and Tabelle means table.

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%Format list of figures
\titlecontents{figure}
  [0em]
  {}
  {\figurename\enspace\thecontentslabel:\enspace}
  {}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}[\vskip10pt]

%Format table of contents
    \titlecontents{table}
  [0em]
  {}
  {\tablename\enspace\thecontentslabel:\enspace}
  {}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}[\vskip10pt]

% No numbering of literature chapter for list of tables
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\listoffigures

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\listoftables
```

The code above makes my LoF and LoT look like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could add \sloppy or possibly \string\sloppy to your \addcontentsline text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This combination of code solved my problem:

```
\sloppy
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\fussy % in the case there is something else after the LOF and LOT.
```

I should probably use the package **microtype** in the future to avoid any of these problems, because it reduces bad boxes and problems with the hyphenation.